# How to check if row level security is enabled for a table in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, row-level-security

Enabling row level security on a table in postgres is pretty straightforward:

```
alter table some_table enable row level security;
```

How would you check to see which tables in a given schema have row level security enabled (for testing)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is stored in [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html)

- `relrowsecurity`  bool        True if table has row level security enabled; see [pg_policy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-policy.html) catalog
- `relforcerowsecurity`     bool        True if row level security (when enabled) will also apply to table owner; see [pg_policy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-policy.html) catalog

So you can use:

```
select relname, relrowsecurity, relforcerowsecurity
from pg_class
where oid = 'your_table_name'::regclass;
```

Alternatively use [`pg_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html)

Comment: `select relname, relrowsecurity, relforcerowsecurity
from pg_class
where relrowsecurity=true or relforcerowsecurity=true;`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if row level security is enabled for lots of tables for a particular schema (in this case public) you can use:

```sql
select relname, relrowsecurity, relforcerowsecurity
  from pg_class
  join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
  where n.nspname = 'public' and relkind = 'r';
```

Comment: What does the `relforcerowsecurity` col represent?